# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on my node api called from angular app on remote device access

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, google-chrome

I have an Node App and an Angular App running on my System (LG Gram- Windows), and the node server is my API server and the angular App is consuming those APIs. The Angular server is served with `--host 0.0.0.0` so that I can access the app through out my Local Network (WiFi). I tried to access the Angular app with my phone and other laptop (HP - Ubuntu), both the devices was able to access angular app, but the login call(Through the Angular APP) to node API from my phone is giving me an error, but the Ubuntu system is fine. I tried calling the Node API directly from both devices and was able to access it and got a response. The Ubuntu system had the same issue with login but it was somehow fixed. What could be the issue.

Comment: What address did you typed when trying to access the angular _server_ ?

Comment: My computers network IP, 192.168.31.82:4200.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, Since both the Node and Angular server was running on the same machine, i have set the API url as `http://localhost:4000/api` which worked on the same laptop but not on my android device, which in fact is calling `http://localhost:4000/api` for the api calls, hence connection error (no server on port 4000 on my android device). When i changed the url to `http://192.168.31.82:4000/api`, my local network IP, it worked.